# TableView как выделять ячейку а не всю строку

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Как в JavaFX TableView щелкая по ячейке выделять отдельно каждую ячейку, а не всю строку. В дальнейшем я бы хотел реализовать копирование содержимого ячейки. Программку пишу отсюда https://metanit.com/java/javafx/4.13.php, ошибок нет, все ок. Просто не знаю как, и можно ли реализовать такое в принципе.

Comment: Не знаю почему все вопросы тут про TableView. Никогда не любил их и всегда старательно избегаю. В custom ListView можно выделить все что угодно, но это потребует больше времени на описание строк и их заполнение.

Comment: @Maxim Благодарю за отклик, а можно какой нибудь пример из вашей практики как ListView поможет мне заменить TableView и дать мне выделять мышью ячейки каждую по отдельности

Comment: @ p_redator В ListView каждая строка описана по некому fxml макету и термин ячейка меняется на полноценный контрол, которому можно привязать любое поведение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<String[]> tableView = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new String[]{"1", "2", "3"},
                new String[]{"4", "5", "6"},
                new String[]{"7", "8", "9"}
        ));
        // возможность выделять конкретную ячейку (без этого выделяются строки)
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        // возможность выделять несколько ячеек через SHIFT/CTRL (либо несколько строк соответственно)
        // без этого можно выделить только одну ячейку
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        // слушатель для реализации реакции на выделение ячеек
        tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().addListener(this::selectCells);

        TableColumn<String[], String> tc1 = new TableColumn<>("Column 1");
        tc1.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[0]));

        TableColumn<String[], String> tc2 = new TableColumn<>("Column 2");
        tc2.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[1]));

        TableColumn<String[], String> tc3 = new TableColumn<>("Column 3");
        tc3.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[2]));

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(tc1, tc2, tc3);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // реакция на выделение ячеек
    private void selectCells(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TablePosition> c) {
        c.getList().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: @ Александр Савостьянов. То что нужно, не могли бы вы подсказать как выводить в методе selectCells вывести содержимое ячейки

Comment: `c.getList().forEach(tablePosition -> System.out.println( tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(tablePosition.getRow())));`